# Prometheus error context deadline exceeded

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus

Trying to get metrics using Prometheus server 
The yaml I am using is

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'student'
    metrics_path: '/student/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['<HOST IP>:8080']
```

The command I used to run the docker file

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 -v <prometheus.yml location>:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

The error I get in Prometheus dashboard

```
Get http://<host ip>:8080/student/actuator/prometheus: context deadline exceeded
```

Comment: "context deadline exceeded" normally means Prometheus is timing out when connecting to the host it's trying to scrape - can you curl/wget the host from the prometheus container?

Comment: I tried with wget I couldnt connect

Comment: Sounds like you found the problem. Check your firewall settings and, if the IP is an internal docket IP, check that it’s valid.

Comment: I resolved the issue by passing --net=host as a parameter in docker

Comment: I know this is a bit late of comment but I had this exact same issue today when getting prom/node-exporter docker container running on raspberry PI. My issue was the firewall. I opened the port in UFW and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by passing --net=host as a parameter in docker